# Get "the request is time out" during sending a put request to AWS storage

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, alamofire

I try to send PUT request to the below link to upload data to AWS storage:

```swift
"https://jpcloud01.s3.amazonaws.com/134/111067134/872/1d38b212-9753-4d02-b87e-fa7f90d95990.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1570334549&Signature=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

But the console always shows the message:

```swift
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://jpcloud01.s3.amazonaws.com/134/111067134/872/1d38b212-9753-4d02-b87e-fa7f90d95990.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Signature=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://jpcloud01.s3.amazonaws.com/134/111067134/872/1d38b212-9753-4d02-b87e-fa7f90d95990.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1570334549&Signature=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4} [-1001]
```

This is my code segment to send PUT request:

with Alamofire 5.0/Swift 5.0

```
        let _ = AF.upload(fileURL, to: uploadURL, method: .put)
            .response {
                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success( _):
                    if let dataHeader = response.response?.allHeaderFields {
                        print(dataHeader)
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    break
                }
                if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
                    print(statusCode)
                }
            }
        .uploadProgress {
            (progeress) in
            let fProgress = Float(progeress.fractionCompleted)
            print("fProgress = \(fProgress)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message normally means that your data is too big to upload it successfully in time.
Maybe try a smaller file or with better internet conditions.

Comment: And It's OK to upload the same file to Youtube by Youtube's REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the request timeout for request. 
As you are getting -1001 which is [NSURLErrorTimedOut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrortimedout?language=objc) then you know this was a timeout.